# StringBuilder.Split in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Anyone know of a good Split procedure that uses StringBuilder in Delphi?

Comment: What makes you think StringBuilder is an appropriate tool for that job?

Comment: Hi, Rob, Since my implementation was building the tokens by appending one character at a time, I figured StringBuilder would be part of the solution.

However, Gerry's StringList.DelimitedText solution works well (and reading its implementation I can see that appending single characters to tokens is a weak solution.  I needed speed because I'm reading 1,600 rows of 1,600 tokens, or 2.5 million tokens!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be better off using TStringlist.DelimitedText (or any other non-abstract TStrings sub-class). It's more of the traditional Delphi way of achieving what string.Split does in .Net (assuming I remember correctly).

e.g. To split on a pipe | character

```
var
  SL : TStrings;
  i : integer;
begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Delimiter := '|';
    SL.StrictDelimiter := True;
    SL.DelimitedText := S;
    for i := SL.Count - 1 do
    begin
      // do whatever with sl[i];
    end;
  finally
   SL.Free;
  end;
end;
```

You may need to handle the QuoteChar property as well

Comment: You should set "SL.StrictDelimiter := true;" to make that work. Otherwise Chr(1)..<space> will be taken as delimiters as well.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. That's MUCH faster than the character by character delete and append I was doing, even with StringBuilder.  Looking at the GetDelimitedText code in Classes.pas I see why. I guess marching a pointer through a string REALLY is faster!

Answer (score 0):

You can also Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672/is-there-an-unformat-method-in-delphi/73750#73750) to this question for a general purpose utility functions `GetStringPart` and `NumStringParts` that allow you to perform split type operations.