# Exist any Delphi RTL function equivalent to swscanf

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm looking for RTL delphi function equivalent to the [sscanf/swscanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkx076cy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) C++ functions. Exist something like that in the RTL delphi functions or I must look for a third-party implementation?

Comment: There's already a similar question, to which I had the pleasure of answering with a bit of code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713/12170

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an inverse  function of *SysUtils.Format* in Delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672/is-there-an-inverse-function-of-sysutils-format-in-delphi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally would simply call the real functions which can be imported from msvcrt.dll.

```
function sscanf(buffer, format: PAnsiChar): Integer; 
    cdecl; varargs; external 'msvcrt.dll';
function swscanf(buffer, format: PWideChar): Integer; 
    cdecl; varargs; external 'msvcrt.dll';
```

These are tried and tested robust implementations of the C standard library functions.

Comment: @WarrenP You need not redistribute msvcrt.dll like you need not redistribute kernel32.dll, gdi32.dll, etc. - it is a part of OS Windows.

Comment: Yes, since Windows 2000, msvcrt is a standard Windows component. It's the C runtime for MSVC6.

Answer (score 1):

You can [download](http://www.da-soft.com/download/unsorted/) Scan function for Delphi, which is ported MSVC RTL function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a port of sscanf at http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/24258 but it looks to pre-date Unicode so may need some tweaks for XE.

Answer (score 0):

These are deprecated functions even in C.  Use something more modern and type-safe to parse your data.  This is going to be a rich source of errors in your application. For example, how do you intend to make a `(wchar_t *)`  C style scanf string function interoperate with Delphi Strings?

Comment: Aren't they deprecated just because their \0 addiction and are the -n versions still allowed ?

Comment: These functions are not deprecated at all.

Comment: The `_s` and `_s_l` versions are not deprecated.