# formatted input from string in Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus, formatted-input

In Pascal (Delphi, Lazarus), there is the `Format()` function for creating a formatted string from a list of variables. It works in a similar way to `sprintf()` function in `C/C++`.

On the other hand, I am not aware of any function which would set variables using a formatted string as `sscanf()` does in `C/C++`.
Did I miss something? How would you achieve a similar effect?

Comment: There's nothing equivalent in the standard library for Delphi.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/72672/576719. Based on some of that I made an almost complete sscanf() function.

Comment: My code was too large to post :(. So you can use the windows swscanf() as well:  `function swscanf(buffer, format: PWideChar): Integer;
    cdecl; varargs; external 'msvcrt.dll';` Example call: `i := swscanf(PChar('42'), PChar('%x'),@j);`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The use of windows functions is not useful for me, as I want to run the program also (and mainly) under linux. The first link provided by @LU RD seems to be useful, however the answer given by **Marco** suits me best, as I use Lazarus (based on FreePascal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free Pascal has a simple [sscanf](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/sscanf.html) and a special [scandatetime](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/dateutils/scandatetime.html) to reverse date format strings ([formatdatetime](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/formatdatetime.html) opposite)

From what I see these routines should work with Delphi too with at worst token modifications.

Note that there is also [writestr](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/writestr.html) and [readstr](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readstr.html) which are more pascal like formatted I/O concepts similar to write/readln but then to/from strings. These are compiler builtin, so won't work with Delphi